# How to fix this checkbox issue for formstack mobile

Tags: formstack

When the website is viewed through mobile, the checkboxes overlap into the box like this.

[image: picture of the formstack issue]

I have tried to edit the iframe through CSS to hide the checkboxes, however that does not work. What other solutions could I try to fix this issue.

Through regular desktop layout it is not a issue.

I have tried editing the iframe through css to for [type="checkbox] and display: none. Even when trying to edit the font for the framestack through css, it does not respond.